# Rate limiting or preventing user requests on the back end with PHP

Tags: php, security, rate-limiting, ddos

When a user visits one of my pages, my site fetches data from an API and logs the user's IP and authorization token in a database.

When a user then visits the page again, I check the database to see if their authorization token is in the database. If it is, I know the user made a request too fast since their last request.

I'm doing this to prevent DDOSing or spam requests.

However, when I check the database to see if the user's current authentication token is in the database, it takes 30ms. I imagine that this latency will increase as user activity increases and the database gets bigger.

Is what I'm doing the correct approach to rate limiting on the back end? Is there something I can do to make the database queries faster?

Is this the wrong approach to DDOS and spam protection all together?

Here's an example of my process

```
<?php
    
    $userIp = "1.0.0.0.1"; // example IP
    
    $binary = true;
    $authorizationToken = hash('sha256', $userIp."randomSalt", $binary); 

    global $dataConnection; // This is my DB connection, I left the code out to simplify it

    $currentTime = new DateTime();
    $currentTime->modify('-1 minute');
    $currentTime = $currentTime->getTimestamp();

    $query = $dataConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE authorization = :authorization
                                        AND ('timeOf' > :currentTime)");

    $query->bindParam(":authorization", $authorizationToken);
    $query->bindParam(":currentTime", $currentTime);
    $query->execute(); // This request takes 30 ms and will continue to increase as the user activity database gets bigger. 

    if($query->rowCount() !== 0){
       echo "UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST";
    }else{
      echo "All API data here";
    }

?>
```

Comment: call to external api and call to the database is exactly the same thing actually, the only difference that instead of ddosing api users can ddos your database. ddos protection is very hard topic and it is actually impossible to do, especially in script which is already being executed (ie request already reached your server, consumed network bandwidth and occupied port on server, and you're already processing it), anyway you can implement some simple throttling scheme this way, but then I suggest some kind of in-memory storage for that, they usually faster even when accessed via network

Comment: My firewall provider will stop DDOS attacks for the most part. Since my site uses asynchronous JavaScript, a user could go into their browser's console and call the JavaScript function which gets data from the server. It's an exploit only someone would do maliciously, so I'm trying to protect from that with the above method.

Comment: When you mention in-memory storage, is that something like php memcached?

Comment: memcached, mongo, redis - there are literally hundreds of them

Comment: If I store authorization keys in apcu cache, how can they be automatically deleted after a minute? Won't the cache start overflowing with keys?

Comment: in simple case you can write cron php script to do this, but majority of key-value storages support key expiration internally

Comment: Awesome, you got me on the right track here. If you answer with PHP acpu or any other in-memory storage that mentions key expiration I'll happily give you credit for the answer!

Comment: https://www.demo2s.com/php/php-apcu-add-key-expires-expires-duration.html

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php